# My svg cuts off when css animation is applied

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a simple artwork in `svg`. When I apply `css` transform scale property, the element which are on edge off the `svg` cuts off. It's like `svg` is restricting boundaries and elements which scales beyond that boundary gets cuts off. I did play around with `viewbox` but nothing seems to work. Here is my `svg` `viewbox` dimensions.

[Link to codepen](https://codepen.io/manjeshrv/pen/GREEryG)

```css
.why-us-text {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}
```

```html
<svg
            version="1.1"
            id="why-us"
            class="why-us"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            x="0px"
            y="0px"
            viewBox="0 0 1829 885.9"
            style="enable-background: new 0 0 1829 885.9"
            xml:space="preserve"
          >
            <style type="text/css">
              .st0 {
                fill: none;
                stroke: #474a54;
                stroke-linecap: round;
                stroke-linejoin: round;
              }
              .st1 {
                enable-background: new;
              }
              .st2 {
                fill: #df9926;
              }
              .st3 {
                fill: #d8dbe8;
              }
              .st4 {
                fill: #0f9ffa;
              }
              .st5 {
                fill: #00ba91;
              }
              .st6 {
                fill: #963596;
              }
              .st7 {
                fill: #ee0324;
              }
            </style>

            <g id="why-us-group_2_" class="why-us-group">
              <line
                id="why-us-line_2_"
                class="st0 why-us-line"
                x1="924.4"
                y1="146.4"
                x2="924.4"
                y2="209.9"
              />
              <g id="why-us-text_2_" class="why-us-text">
                <g class="st1">
                  <path
                    class="st4"
                    d="M781.2,105c4-3.3,7.2-6.1,9.6-8.2c2.3-2.1,4.3-4.4,5.9-6.8c1.6-2.4,2.4-4.7,2.4-6.9c0-1.7-0.4-3-1.2-4
                c-0.8-1-2-1.4-3.5-1.4c-1.6,0-2.8,0.6-3.7,1.8c-0.9,1.2-1.3,2.8-1.3,5h-10.2c0.1-3.5,0.8-6.4,2.3-8.8c1.4-2.4,3.3-4.1,5.6-5.2
                c2.3-1.1,4.9-1.7,7.8-1.7c4.9,0,8.6,1.3,11.1,3.8c2.5,2.5,3.8,5.8,3.8,9.9c0,4.4-1.5,8.5-4.5,12.3c-3,3.8-6.9,7.5-11.5,11.1h16.7
                v8.6h-31.1v-7.9C780.7,105.4,781.3,104.9,781.2,105z"
                  />
                  <path
                    class="st4"
                    d="M813.9,79.6v-9.9h17.2V115h-11V79.6H813.9z"
                  />
                  <path
                    class="st4"
                    d="M870.9,98.1h-10.8v11h-10v-11h-10.8v-9.5H850V77.5h10v11.1h10.8V98.1z"
                  />
                  <path
                    class="st4"
                    d="M928.8,71.5l-15.1,29.1V115h-10.6v-14.4l-15.1-29.1h12l8.4,18.2l8.4-18.2H928.8z"
                  />
                  <path
                    class="st4"
                    d="M965.5,100.3h-24c0.2,2.1,0.9,3.8,2.1,4.9c1.2,1.1,2.7,1.7,4.5,1.7c2.6,0,4.5-1.1,5.5-3.3h11.3
                c-0.6,2.3-1.6,4.3-3.1,6.1c-1.5,1.8-3.4,3.2-5.7,4.3c-2.3,1-4.8,1.5-7.6,1.5c-3.4,0-6.4-0.7-9.1-2.2c-2.6-1.4-4.7-3.5-6.2-6.2
                c-1.5-2.7-2.2-5.8-2.2-9.4s0.7-6.7,2.2-9.4c1.5-2.7,3.5-4.8,6.2-6.2c2.6-1.4,5.7-2.2,9.1-2.2c3.3,0,6.3,0.7,8.9,2.1
                c2.6,1.4,4.6,3.4,6.1,6c1.5,2.6,2.2,5.6,2.2,9.1C965.7,98.1,965.7,99.2,965.5,100.3z M954.9,94.4c0-1.8-0.6-3.3-1.9-4.3
                c-1.2-1.1-2.8-1.6-4.7-1.6c-1.8,0-3.3,0.5-4.5,1.5c-1.2,1-2,2.5-2.3,4.4H954.9z"
                  />
                  <path
                    class="st4"
                    d="M971.2,88.3c1.3-2.7,3.2-4.8,5.5-6.2c2.3-1.4,4.9-2.2,7.8-2.2c2.4,0,4.6,0.5,6.4,1.5c1.8,1,3.3,2.3,4.2,3.9
                v-4.9h10.6V115h-10.6v-4.9c-1,1.6-2.5,2.9-4.3,3.9s-4,1.5-6.4,1.5c-2.8,0-5.4-0.7-7.7-2.2c-2.3-1.5-4.1-3.6-5.5-6.3
                c-1.3-2.7-2-5.8-2-9.4C969.2,94.1,969.9,91,971.2,88.3z M992.9,91.4c-1.5-1.5-3.3-2.3-5.4-2.3c-2.1,0-3.9,0.8-5.4,2.3
                c-1.5,1.5-2.2,3.6-2.2,6.2c0,2.6,0.7,4.7,2.2,6.3c1.5,1.6,3.3,2.3,5.4,2.3c2.1,0,3.9-0.8,5.4-2.3c1.5-1.5,2.2-3.6,2.2-6.3
                C995.1,95.1,994.4,93,992.9,91.4z"
                  />
                  <path
                    class="st4"
                    d="M1028.6,81.7c1.9-1.1,3.9-1.6,6.2-1.6v11.2h-2.9c-2.6,0-4.6,0.6-6,1.7c-1.3,1.1-2,3.1-2,6V115h-10.6V80.4
                h10.6v5.8C1025.2,84.3,1026.8,82.8,1028.6,81.7z"
                  />
                  <path
                    class="st4"
                    d="M1045.9,114c-2.4-1-4.2-2.4-5.6-4.2s-2.1-3.8-2.3-6h10.5c0.1,1.2,0.7,2.2,1.7,2.9c1,0.7,2.2,1.1,3.7,1.1
                c1.3,0,2.3-0.3,3.1-0.8c0.7-0.5,1.1-1.2,1.1-2c0-1-0.5-1.7-1.5-2.2c-1-0.5-2.7-1-5-1.6c-2.5-0.6-4.5-1.2-6.2-1.8s-3.1-1.7-4.3-3
                c-1.2-1.4-1.8-3.3-1.8-5.6c0-2,0.5-3.8,1.6-5.4c1.1-1.6,2.7-2.9,4.8-3.9c2.1-1,4.7-1.4,7.6-1.4c4.3,0,7.8,1.1,10.3,3.2
                c2.5,2.1,3.9,5,4.3,8.6h-9.8c-0.2-1.2-0.7-2.1-1.6-2.9c-0.9-0.7-2.1-1.1-3.5-1.1c-1.2,0-2.2,0.2-2.9,0.7c-0.7,0.5-1,1.1-1,2
                c0,1,0.5,1.7,1.6,2.2c1.1,0.5,2.7,1,4.9,1.5c2.6,0.7,4.7,1.3,6.3,2c1.6,0.6,3,1.7,4.2,3.1c1.2,1.4,1.8,3.3,1.9,5.7
                c0,2-0.6,3.8-1.7,5.4c-1.1,1.6-2.8,2.8-4.9,3.8c-2.1,0.9-4.6,1.4-7.4,1.4C1051,115.5,1048.3,115,1045.9,114z"
                  />
                </g>
                <g class="st1">
                  <path
                    d="M852.5,14.7v6.5h7.7v3h-7.7V31h8.6v3h-12.3V11.7h12.3v3H852.5z"
                  />
                  <path
                    d="M873.2,25.1l5.7,8.9h-4.1l-3.8-6l-3.6,6h-3.8l5.7-8.7l-5.7-9h4.1l3.8,6l3.6-6h3.8L873.2,25.1z"
                  />
                  <path
                    d="M887.8,16.9c1.1-0.6,2.3-0.8,3.6-0.8c1.5,0,2.9,0.4,4.2,1.1c1.3,0.8,2.3,1.8,3,3.2c0.7,1.4,1.1,2.9,1.1,4.7
                c0,1.8-0.4,3.4-1.1,4.8c-0.7,1.4-1.7,2.5-3,3.3c-1.3,0.8-2.7,1.2-4.2,1.2c-1.3,0-2.5-0.3-3.6-0.8c-1-0.5-1.9-1.2-2.6-2v10.9h-3.6
                v-26h3.6V19C885.9,18.1,886.7,17.5,887.8,16.9z M895.2,22c-0.5-0.9-1.2-1.6-2-2c-0.8-0.5-1.7-0.7-2.6-0.7c-0.9,0-1.8,0.2-2.6,0.7
                c-0.8,0.5-1.5,1.2-2,2c-0.5,0.9-0.8,2-0.8,3.2s0.3,2.3,0.8,3.2c0.5,0.9,1.2,1.6,2,2.1c0.8,0.5,1.7,0.7,2.6,0.7
                c0.9,0,1.8-0.2,2.6-0.7c0.8-0.5,1.5-1.2,2-2.1c0.5-0.9,0.8-2,0.8-3.2C896,23.9,895.7,22.8,895.2,22z"
                  />
                  <path
                    d="M919.3,26.5h-13.5c0.1,1.4,0.6,2.5,1.6,3.4c0.9,0.9,2.1,1.3,3.5,1.3c2,0,3.3-0.8,4.2-2.5h3.9c-0.5,1.6-1.5,2.9-2.9,4
                s-3.1,1.6-5.2,1.6c-1.7,0-3.2-0.4-4.5-1.1c-1.3-0.8-2.4-1.8-3.1-3.2s-1.1-3-1.1-4.8c0-1.8,0.4-3.4,1.1-4.8
                c0.7-1.4,1.8-2.4,3.1-3.2c1.3-0.7,2.9-1.1,4.6-1.1c1.7,0,3.1,0.4,4.4,1.1c1.3,0.7,2.3,1.7,3,3.1c0.7,1.3,1.1,2.8,1.1,4.5
                C919.5,25.4,919.4,26,919.3,26.5z M915.7,23.6c0-1.3-0.5-2.4-1.4-3.2s-2.1-1.2-3.5-1.2c-1.3,0-2.3,0.4-3.2,1.2
                c-0.9,0.8-1.4,1.9-1.6,3.2H915.7z"
                  />
                  <path
                    d="M928.8,16.8c0.9-0.5,1.9-0.8,3.2-0.8v3.8H931c-1.4,0-2.5,0.4-3.2,1.1s-1.1,2-1.1,3.8V34H923V16.4h3.6v2.6
                C927.2,18,927.9,17.3,928.8,16.8z"
                  />
                  <path
                    d="M935.5,13.4c-0.4-0.4-0.7-1-0.7-1.7s0.2-1.2,0.7-1.7s1-0.7,1.7-0.7c0.6,0,1.2,0.2,1.6,0.7s0.7,1,0.7,1.7
                s-0.2,1.2-0.7,1.7c-0.4,0.4-1,0.7-1.6,0.7C936.5,14,936,13.8,935.5,13.4z M939,16.4V34h-3.6V16.4H939z"
                  />
                  <path
                    d="M956.4,16.9c1.1,0.6,2,1.4,2.6,2.6c0.6,1.1,0.9,2.5,0.9,4.1V34h-3.6v-9.9c0-1.6-0.4-2.8-1.2-3.6
                c-0.8-0.8-1.9-1.3-3.2-1.3s-2.4,0.4-3.2,1.3c-0.8,0.8-1.2,2.1-1.2,3.6V34h-3.6V16.4h3.6v2c0.6-0.7,1.4-1.3,2.3-1.7
                c0.9-0.4,1.9-0.6,3-0.6C954.1,16.1,955.3,16.4,956.4,16.9z"
                  />
                  <path
                    d="M964.4,20.4c0.7-1.4,1.8-2.4,3.1-3.2c1.3-0.7,2.8-1.1,4.5-1.1c2.1,0,3.9,0.5,5.3,1.5c1.4,1,2.3,2.5,2.8,4.3h-3.9
                c-0.3-0.9-0.8-1.6-1.5-2c-0.7-0.5-1.6-0.7-2.7-0.7c-1.5,0-2.7,0.5-3.6,1.6c-0.9,1.1-1.3,2.5-1.3,4.4c0,1.9,0.4,3.4,1.3,4.4
                c0.9,1.1,2.1,1.6,3.6,1.6c2.1,0,3.5-0.9,4.2-2.8h3.9c-0.5,1.8-1.5,3.2-2.9,4.3s-3.2,1.6-5.2,1.6c-1.7,0-3.2-0.4-4.5-1.1
                c-1.3-0.8-2.3-1.8-3.1-3.2s-1.1-3-1.1-4.8C963.3,23.4,963.7,21.8,964.4,20.4z"
                  />
                  <path
                    d="M999.8,26.5h-13.5c0.1,1.4,0.6,2.5,1.6,3.4c0.9,0.9,2.1,1.3,3.5,1.3c2,0,3.3-0.8,4.2-2.5h3.9c-0.5,1.6-1.5,2.9-2.9,4
                s-3.1,1.6-5.2,1.6c-1.7,0-3.2-0.4-4.5-1.1c-1.3-0.8-2.4-1.8-3.1-3.2c-0.8-1.4-1.1-3-1.1-4.8c0-1.8,0.4-3.4,1.1-4.8
                c0.7-1.4,1.8-2.4,3.1-3.2s2.9-1.1,4.6-1.1c1.7,0,3.1,0.4,4.4,1.1c1.3,0.7,2.3,1.7,3,3.1c0.7,1.3,1.1,2.8,1.1,4.5
                C999.9,25.4,999.9,26,999.8,26.5z M996.1,23.6c0-1.3-0.5-2.4-1.4-3.2s-2.1-1.2-3.5-1.2c-1.3,0-2.3,0.4-3.2,1.2
                c-0.9,0.8-1.4,1.9-1.6,3.2H996.1z"
                  />
                </g>
              </g>
              <g id="why-us-card_2_" class="why-us-card">
                <g id="Group_25" transform="translate(467.634 341.299)">
                  <path
                    id="Path_10"
                    class="st3"
                    d="M437.2,185.3c27.2,0,54.3,3,80.9,8.9c15.5,3.4,31.1-5.3,36.5-20.2l80.7-222.5
                c6-16.4-2.5-34.6-18.9-40.6c-0.8-0.3-1.6-0.5-2.4-0.8c-57.6-15.7-117-23.7-176.7-23.6c-59.7,0-119.1,7.9-176.7,23.6
                c-16.9,4.7-26.7,22.1-22.1,39c0.2,0.8,0.5,1.6,0.8,2.4L319.9,174c5.4,14.9,21,23.6,36.5,20.2C382.9,188.3,410,185.3,437.2,185.3z
                "
                  />
                </g>
                <path
                  id="Path_43"
                  class="st4"
                  d="M904.8,535c27.2,0,54.3,3,80.9,8.9c15.5,3.4,31.1-5.3,36.5-20.2l80.7-222.5
            c6-16.4-2.5-34.6-18.9-40.6c-0.8-0.3-1.6-0.5-2.4-0.8c-57.6-15.7-117-23.6-176.7-23.6c-59.7,0-119.1,7.9-176.7,23.6
            c-16.9,4.7-26.7,22.1-22.1,39c0.2,0.8,0.5,1.6,0.8,2.4l80.7,222.5c5.4,14.9,21,23.6,36.5,20.2C850.5,538,877.6,535,904.8,535z"
                />

                <image
                  style="overflow: visible; enable-background: new"
                  width="512"
                  height="512"
                  id="days_-_Copy"
                  xlink:href="./img/559815E5.png"
                  transform="matrix(0.3299 0 0 0.3299 839.319 293.876)"
                ></image>
              </g>
            </g>
          </svg>
```

Comment: SVG was to large to place here. I have provided a link to codepen.

Comment: Here, I edited my question and added minimized svg to produce same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Solution is to set overflow: visible on svg element. By default svg overflow is set to hidden.